# FastDictCache in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ipython, python-internals

I'm asking a very basic question.
I was looking through the documentation of `dict` as follows:

```
In [1]: ?dict
Init signature: dict(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:
dict() -> new empty dictionary
dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's
    (key, value) pairs
dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
    d = {}
    for k, v in iterable:
        d[k] = v
dict(**kwargs) -> new dictionary initialized with the name=value pairs
    in the keyword argument list.  For example:  dict(one=1, two=2)
Type:           type
Subclasses:     OrderedDict, defaultdict, Counter, _EnumDict, Bunch, Config, Struct, ColorSchemeTable, FastDictCache, _CharSizesCache, ...
```

Above I got to know which all subclasses does `dict` have. I have used `OrderedDict`, `defaultdict`, `Counter`, `Bunch` but I couldn't find any online resources on `FastDictCache`.

What's `FastDictCache` in python? Which package has it? How to use it?

Comment: Seems to be this: https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/prompt_toolkit/cache.py#L63 - I'm guessing the subclasses list is dynamically generated from site-packages

Comment: good find - i would assume rather that it's built from the subclass list from `dict` live in the session you are running. since you are in IPython, and it uses prompt_toolkit (afaik), this module would have been imported and so that would be in the subclass list for `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says:

- the subclass list comes from the currently extant objects, via `cls.__subclasses__()`:

```
>>> class Foo(dict):
...     pass
...
>>> dict.__subclasses__()
[
  <class 'collections.OrderedDict'>,
  <class 'collections.defaultdict'>,
  <class 'collections.Counter'>,
  <class '__main__.Foo'>
]
>>>
```

- `FastDictCache` comes from `python-prompt-toolkit`: https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/prompt_toolkit/cache.py#L63
- You can use it by importing it, passing it a `get_value` callable and accessing it like a dict, but looking at the implementation, it looks like the builtin [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) would work as well for many usecases.

Comment: Thank you I have tried this. But the question is - "What's FastDictCache in python? Which package has it? How to use it?"

Comment: Well, the comment answers it.

Comment: It doesn't answer completely

Comment: How about now, then?